# StackExchange Android app for on Tablet

Tags: discussion, android

Is there any Android app designed for Tablet?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for Stack Remote. There are many Android Applications for Tablets. As for a Stack Android App, Stack Remote is working perfectly on my Motorola Xoom as well as on Samsung Galaxy Note.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for the same today, and from what I see, no current apps in Google Play seem to **optimised** for tablets, but couple come close:

**Stack Remote** : the way it shows selected stack QA sites list on to a single screen, you may find it convenient to browse it on a tablet screen.

**Stack Anywhere** : the answer reading is a bit annoying (since it assumes you have a small screen and shows you one answer at a time), but the rest of the interface is convenient for tablet usage.